# INNER JOIN not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a mysql join i'm trying to complete.
This is my code:

```
SELECT title, books.`author_id`, books.`publisher_id`, books.`format_id`, books.`genre_id`, pages, isbn, description, DATE_FORMAT(release_date, '%M, %d, %Y') 
FROM `books`
INNER JOIN `authors` ON (`authors`.`author_id`= `books`.`author_id`)
INNER JOIN `publishers` ON (`publishers`.`publisher_id`= `books`.`publisher_id`)
INNER JOIN `formats` ON (`formats`.`format_id`= `books`.`format_id`)
INNER JOIN `genres` ON (`genres`.`genre_id`= `books`.`genre_id`)`
```

authors, publishers, formats and genres are all separate tables each with two columns.  author_id and author in the case of the authors table, and the same format for the others.

The join doesn't seem to work no matter what i do, please help me to see where i've gone wrong.

Comment: What does it mean doesn't work? Do you get error? No results? What?

Comment: -1 for saying _it does not work_ and not saying _how is it supposed to work_.

Comment: the foreign keys from author_id are displayed and not the author columns values.

Comment: @Webmorpher I don't see any author columns in the `SELECT` list, other than `books.authorid`. Of course they won't display.

Comment: when i get rid of the books. on books.author_id the error "Column 'author_id' in field list is ambiguous" is displayed.

Comment: @Webmorpher, You need to add author columns like `authors.name, authors.birthplace, authors.whatever` explicitly.  Simply joining in the table doesn't make columns appear in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the select part of your query.

```
SELECT title, books.`author_id`, books.`publisher_id`, books.`format_id`, books.`genre_id`
```

You are selecting the author_id, publisher_id, format_id and genre_id from the books table, and nothing from the joined tables, so it is no wonder that you are missing the values you want.

```
SELECT title, books.`author_id`, authors.`author`, books.`publisher_id`, publishers.`publisher`, books.`format_id`, formats.`format`, books.`genre_id`, genres.`genre`
```

This will produce the values you want in addition to the id values.

Answer (score 0):

I think that once you've started to use escaped column names you should stick with it for whole query. The same for using prefixed column names (with table name).

The second thing is release date, you should declare name manually for it with `DATE_FORMAT(release_date, '%M, %d, %Y') AS release_date` (formatting date should be matter of presentation layer not model (getting from db) so I'd be better to format date with `date()` when outputing it).

Anyway your query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT books.`title`, books.`author_id`, books.`publisher_id`, books.`format_id`, 
       books.`genre_id`, books.`pages`, books.`isbn`, books.`description`,
       DATE_FORMAT(books.`release_date`, '%M, %d, %Y') AS `release_date`,
       -- Based on your commend I assume you want to use this:
       authors.`name` as `author_name` -- ...
FROM `books`
INNER JOIN `authors` ON (`authors`.`author_id`= `books`.`author_id`)
INNER JOIN `publishers` ON (`publishers`.`publisher_id`= `books`.`publisher_id`)
INNER JOIN `formats` ON (`formats`.`format_id`= `books`.`format_id`)
INNER JOIN `genres` ON (`genres`.`genre_id`= `books`.`genre_id`)`
```